# Execute a pipeline after a completion pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a first pipeline that ingest data for multiple country from BigQuery to Azure, it's an operation that copy bigquery transformed data into azure.

On Data Factory, i create multiple folders for each country that will have multiple pipeline, for example, a specific machine learning model only for 1 or 2 countries, a data prepration pipeline for an application for only 5 countries etc.

I think i need this folder construction for each market to keep it clear for anybody that needs to implement a pipeline and avoid errors.

My main problem by doing that is how i can call, for example, a machine learning pipeline in my folder UK that can only start after the first pipeline, the bigquery copy data to azure, completed ?

I can't call the Execution Pipeline activity because my first pipeline bigquerytoazure  is executed by himself, it's the very important step that needs to be executed before any other pipeline can be executed.

Is there any way to call completed pipeline without the Execution Pipeline activated ?

I thought about creating a dummy blob storage in the first pipeline that can work as a trigger for all pipeline after this first one ?

Thanks by advance, hope i was clear.

Comment: Where is  BigQuery data stored in Azure?

Comment: Azure DB SQL ...

Comment: The dummy blob works perfectly, I tried it but maybe there is a cleaner way to do so ?

Comment: Data Factory event trigger based on the blob storage. I think that's the best way.  Another way you can using logic app to listen the BigQuery table in SQL database, if the BigQuery table modified, then execute a data factory pipeline. Create a work flow with Logic app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data Factory event trigger based on the blob storage. I think that's the best way.

Another way you can think about using [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview), add a trigger to listen the BigQuery table in SQL database, if the BigQuery table modified, then execute a data factory pipeline. Create a work flow for the pipelines run.

[image]

Work flow:

1. SQL Server Trigger: when an item is modified.
2. Add a parallel branch
3. Data Factory Action: Get a pipeline run

Reference: [Automate workflows for SQL Server or Azure SQL Database by using
    Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you ! Thats a cleaner way i think :)